# jQuery (JS?) How can I filter elements based on values in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, filtering

I have a series of elements on a page that I want users to be able to filter.

The elements have tags stored in a data attribute. I have the it set up so that when the user clicks one of the tag names in the filter area (#filters), the tag is added to an array. It's removed from the array when the tag is clicked again.

When a tag is clicked, I want jQuery to scan through the elements to be filtered (#elementstofilter) and hide ones that do not have all of the tags that are currently held in the filter array.

The filter is meant to be an AND filter, so if **Tag1** and **Tag2** were selected, it would only show elements that had both tags (#d1 and #d3 in the example below).

I feel like the solution is probably pretty simple, but I'm having a hard time finding an answer. Maybe there's a more effective way of doing this entirely.

```
<ul id="filters">
<li data-filter="tag1">Tag1</li>
<li data-filter="tag2">Tag2</li>
<li data-filter="tag3">Tag3</li>
<li data-filter="tag4">Tag4</li>
<li data-filter="tag5">Tag5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="elementstofilter">
<li class="project" id="d1" data-tags="tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5"></li>
<li class="project" id="d2" data-tags="tag1"></li>
<li class="project" id="d3" data-tags="tag1 tag2 tag5"></li>
<li class="project" id="d4" data-tags="tag3 tag4"></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the jQ that I've got so far. There's not a lot to it yet.

```
var filter=[]; // Array to hold filter values
$('#filters li').click(function() {
    var sel=$(this).attr('data-filter');
    if($(this).hasClass('sel')) { // Add or remove values from the filter
        filter.push(sel);
    } else {
        filter=$.grep(filter, function(value) {
            return value!=sel;
        });
    }
    if(filter.length==0) { // Show all projects if no filters are selected
        $('.project:hidden').show();
    } else { // At least one filter is on
        /*
        if all of the values in the filter are represented in the data-tags of a project
            if that project is hidden
                show that project
        else
            hide that project
        */
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the JS you are using now

Comment: I am on mobile right now but it sounds like the answer is to implement the jQuery filter() function when selecting your <li> tags

Comment: @MonkeyZeus sounds correct, Here's the jquery documentation for `filter()` http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Is there a reason that you will be using an array for this? instead of instantly hiding and showing with a class?

Comment: @ntgCleaner I'm only using the array because I couldn't think of a way to implement it without one. It seemed like the logical starting point. How would you go about it using just classes?

Comment: I'm going to try to write a fiddle for you.

Comment: That would be so much easier if you used the tags as classes

Comment: @Ben I'm not married to using the data attribute. How would the solution be easier using classes for the tags?

Comment: @ArthurBath because you could use standard selectors, eg. `$('.project').hide().filter('.tag1,.tag2').show()` would hide all except tag1 and tag2

Comment: @Ben YES! This is exactly the nudge I needed. Everybody that said to use jQ filter() was right. This is definitely the simplest way to do it.

Comment: I've added it as an answer. Feel free to accept ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to use your tags as classes so you can use standard selectors.

The filtering becomes very easy:

```
$('.project').hide().filter('.tag1,.tag2').show();
```

Comment: Using classes instead of data attributes made it much easier. Here's the Fiddle with the working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/arthurbath/xh6ft/2/

Comment: Kudos to everyone else for trying to make it work with data- attributes though.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little dirty... Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99Ne4/)

I've gotten rid of the array idea (although it's not a bad idea, so don't get me wrong) and just used simple classes to show and hide.  I'm sure someone will show you a "faster" or "better" way of doing this, and may even think arrays will be faster in certain situations, but this is how I would handle it.  I've also added a `.show` class to all of your project lis

Assuming I am understanding what you've said, I've made the jquery get tag of the clicked tag

```
$('#filters li').click(function(){
   var tag = $(this).attr('data-filter');
```

This will store the variable of the clicked tag (just like you have)

Then I loop through all of the project tags

```
$('.project').each(function(){
```

And write some code to show and hide them if they have that tag

```
    var tags = $(this).attr('data-tags').split(" "); //Get all of the tag names and put them in an array called tags
    for(var i=0; i < tags.length; i++){ //Loop through all of the tags
        if(tags[i] == tag){ //if one of the tags == the tag
            if($(this).hasClass('show')){ //and if it is showing
                console.log("hide");
                $(this).removeClass("show").addClass("hide"); //hide it
            } else {
                console.log("show");
                $(this).removeClass("hide").addClass("show"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will, please redirect to the page what I do for your logic, as below:

```
var filters = [];
$("#filters").on("click", "li", function() {
    var $scope = $(this);
    var filterTag = $scope.data("filter");
    if ($scope.hasClass("sel-filter")) {
        filters = $.grep(filters, function(obj) {
            return filterTag != obj;
        });
        $scope.removeClass("sel-filter");
    } else {
        filters.push(filterTag);
        $scope.addClass("sel-filter");
    }

    if (filters.length === 0) {
        $(".project:hidden").show();
    } else {
        $("#elementstofilter").trigger("projectToFilter");
    }
});

$("#elementstofilter").bind("projectToFilter", function() {
    $.each($(".project", $(this)), function(i, obj) {
        var $obj = $(obj);
        var storeTags = $obj.data("tags").split(" ");
        var found = false;
        for (var j in filters) {
            if ($.inArray(filters[j], storeTags) == -1) {
                $obj.hide();
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            $obj.show();
        }
    });
});
```

[click here to see run result.](http://jsfiddle.net/richie_guo/K6HNV/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution sticking to the array.  It's a bit long and I'm sure it can be compressed but the logic is there.
http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/PczUm/4/

```
var filter=[]; // Array to hold filter values 21270555
var matchCount=[]; //Array to hold matched count
$('.project').each(function(i){
    matchCount[i]=0;
});
var totalFilter=0;
$('#filters li').click(function() {
    var sel=$(this).attr('data-filter');
    if ($(this).css("color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
        $(this).css("color","black");
    } else {
        $(this).css("color","red");
    };
    if($.inArray(sel,filter)===-1) {
        filter.push(sel);
        totalFilter+=1;
        $('.project').each(function(i) {
            var target=$(this).attr('data-tags');
            if (target.indexOf(sel)>=0) {
                matchCount[i]+=1;
                if (matchCount[i] == totalFilter) {
                    $(this).css("display","none");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("display","list-item");
                };
            } else {
                $(this).css("display","list-item");
            };
        });
    } else {
        filter=$.grep(filter, function(value) {
            return value!=sel;
        });
        totalFilter -= 1;
        $('.project').each(function(i) {
            var target=$(this).attr('data-tags');
            if (target.indexOf(sel)>=0) {
                matchCount[i]-=1;
                if (matchCount[i] !== totalFilter || totalFilter == 0) {
                    $(this).css("display","list-item");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("display","none");
                };
            } else {
                if (matchCount[i] == totalFilter && totalFilter != 0) {
                    $(this).css("display","none");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("display","list-item");
                };
            };
        });    
    };
});
```